# Xamarin IOS SQLite

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

I am creating an app where user needs to input the client information and this information will be sent to the next page and will be shown in a table format. I am able to insert the values but unable to retrive it in the table format. Please help.

```
    private string pathtoDatabase;
    public RoofExisting(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        var documentFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        pathtoDatabase = Path.Combine(documentFolder, "ClientInfo_db.db");

        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(pathtoDatabase))
        {
            var con = connection.Table<ClientInfo>();
            foreach (var item in con)
            {
                ClientInfo Info = new ClientInfo(item.projectno, item.ClientName, item.CCompany, item.Caddress, item.CPostal, item.CPhonen, item.CEmail);

                //Adding in the table view
                CNinfo.Source = new TableSource(Info, this);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
class TableSource:UITableViewSource
{
    protected string[] tableItems;
    protected String cellidentifier = "TableCell";
    ViewController owner;
    private ClientInfo info;
    private RoofExisting roofExisting;

    public TableSource(String[] items, ViewController owner)
    {
        tableItems = items;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public TableSource(ClientInfo info, RoofExisting roofExisting)
    {
        this.info = info;
        this.roofExisting = roofExisting;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return tableItems.Length;
    }
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UIAlertController alertcontroller = UIAlertController.Create("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alertcontroller.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("ok",UIAlertActionStyle.Default,null));
        owner.PresentViewController(alertcontroller,true,null);

        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath,true);
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellidentifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellidentifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume one error is that you are setting a single `CNInfo` (whatever that is) inside a foreach - that means you are overwriting it each time and only the last one will work.

I would refactor this line (at least):

```
CNinfo.Source = new TableSource(Info, this);
```

Also, you have two constructors that do completely different things. Calling `public TableSource(ClientInfo info, RoofExisting roofExisting)` means that `tableItems` and `owner` will be null and throw a `NullReferenceException` in your override methods since they are only set in the other constructor.

I haven't messed with a `UITableViewSource` in a while but I would *think* that it would hold a *collection* of items. You are making a `UITableViewSource` for *each* `ContactInfo`.

These two classes need to be refactored. Maybe look up a few more examples about creating a `UITableViewSource` before attempting to change this code so you'll have a better idea of how to implement it.